# Difference between two filtered row Spotfire

Tags: filter, difference, spotfire

I'm in problems with Spotfire.  I have filtered my dataset by feature (dat_delivery) and I would like to make de difference between rows with the same dateprice. I know that spotfire have the difference aggregation method but it doesn't work. (I'm a Rookie)
Any idea?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "make the difference between rows"? In general, to base an aggregation based on another column, you do: an_aggregation([column1]) over ([column2])

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mickael M. that more information is needed to get an answer to this question, but I just want to note that you said, "I have filtered my data."  When you create a calculated column, Spotfire will take all of your data into account, not just the filtered data.  Sometimes this is a big deal and sometimes not.

If you want to calculate only on filtered data, you will need to write an expression on the axis of a visualization, not create a calculated column.